# Restrict website access based on Private IP address using .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, proxy, ip-address

I am trying to give access to my site to specifc IP Address. If I add my private IP Address it is not working(Gave me 403 error). Then I try adding my public IP and I was able to access the site.

I have tried adding below code to .htaccess file:

**TRY 1**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX\.XX\.XX\.XX\.XX$
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

**TRY 2**

```
order allow,deny
allow from XX.XXX.XX.XXX
deny from all
```

Can you help me how I can give access to my private IP? Is there a way I can give website access to Private IP address?

Comment: Are you trying to use `192.0.2.0` as your actual private IP address? [You can't use that particular address for anything except documentation examples](https://search.arin.net/rdap/?query=192.0.2.0). And, unless your web server is on your private network it will never see a visit from your private address. Network Address Translation on your router conceals it from the public network.

Comment: The IP Addresses I provided are just examples.

Comment: Nevertheless what @O.Jones writes is true: private addresses are irrelevant if you access that server via your local network boundaries. Which is why you cannot limit access based on those private addresses.

Comment: is there any other work around for this that I can use? @arkascha

Comment: You can use other forms of authorization, obviously. If you really want to rely on a network level solution you could think about tunneling the request. That would allow to authorize by loopback address. But ovviously that means you need an option to open such a tunnel. Read: you need ssh access to the server side.